# Problems directly using PhantomJS in node.js

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm attempting to use PhantomJS, and I've installed it  via NPM.
I can't seem to run any of the of the examples, in fact I can't even run:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'
```

Is there anything i'm missing? I'm using a few other modules that I've installed via NPM in the same directory with no issues

Comment: `ls node_modules` is the module there?

Comment: Also, can try `npm list` and `npm list -g` to see what is locally or globally installed

Answer (score 53, accepted):

PhantomJS is **not** for Node.js. You are likely running the examples through `node` binary.

Read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start) documentation carefully and you'll see that every single PhantomJS example need to be invoked like:

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

Note that there is a *bridge* between Node.js and PhantomJS. In that case, you need to follow the given examples for that particular bridge (there are a few different ones).

Comment: For future reference: Probably the most popular bridge is [phantom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantom).

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
var page = new WebPage();
```

Example of code :

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open('http://example.com', function(status) {
console.log("Status: " + status);
if(status === "success") {
page.render('example.png');
}
phantom.exit();
});
```