# How to require modules from another module - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, phantomjs

I have my nodejs app consisting of 2 files, index.js - the main one, capable of routing and all other stuff, and ping.js - that is using phantomJS functionality. In my index.js I have following call:

```
var phantomMy = require('./ping.js');
```

and in ping.js I need standard module of phantomJS - webpage, so I have call like this

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
```

but this gives me error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    ..
```

What am I doing wrong - maybe not only from a syntax but from architectural point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems using PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487321/problems-using-phantomjs)

Comment: show us the webpage structure. I cannot find module `webpage` on npmjs.
There're 2 issue may occur : 
1/. Wrong destination in `require(pathTofile)`
2/. The structure of webpage is not correct. must be return `module.exports = function() {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpage module is a module of PhantomJS. If you run the file using `node index.js` it will give that error. You need to run it as `phantomjs index.js` for it to work. If you are trying to communicate with phantomjs, I suggest you to look into some other modules like [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) instead of writing your own.